# can't write pdf in R

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I try to save a ggplot in a pdf in my wd. The pdf file is created but does not contain anything. Here is what I have :

```
pdf("enrich_prof_eu.pdf",height = 7,width =10)
par(mfrow=c(1,2),mar=c(4, 4.1, 5.5, 1) + 
0.1,mgp=c(2.1,0.7,0),cex.axis=1.2,pch=3)

for (i in el){
df=data.frame(horizon = c("h1", "h2", "h3", "h4"), val =yeubis[,i])
ggplot(df, aes(x=val,y=horizon)) +
geom_point() +
geom_segment(aes(x=df$val[1], y=df$horizon[1], xend=df$val[2], 
yend=df$horizon[2])) +
geom_segment(aes(x=df$val[2], y=df$horizon[2], xend=df$val[3], 
yend=df$horizon[3])) +
geom_segment(aes(x=df$val[3], y=df$horizon[3], xend=df$val[4], 
yend=df$horizon[4])) +
scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df$horizon)))+
scale_x_continuous(position = "top") +
labs(x=paste(i,"[ppm]"))
}
dev.off()
```

The loop and the ggplot are working. I don't have any error message. But still I can't open the pdf because nothing is writen in it ?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: you want to `print()` ggplots inside a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `pdf()` and `dev.off()` with `ggplot2`. Use `ggsave()`

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x, y)) + geom_segment(...)
ggsave("enrich_prof_eu.pdf")
```

See `?ggsave` for more options, such as output dimensions, units, etc.

### EDIT

In response to your comment, place the `ggsave()` inside the `for()` loop, and save the plot to a different file name each time. For example:

```
for (i in seq_along(variables)) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_segment(...)
  ggsave(paste0("enrich_prof_eu_", i, ".pdf"))
}
```

This pastes the iteration number into the filename so the same file isn't overwritten each time.

Comment: Indeed it works, but it only saves the last plot. 
this is due to the parameters : 
`plot=last_plot()`. How do I change this parameter so it saves all the plot of my loop ?

Comment: @jo.H See my edit for an approach you could use to solve this.

Comment: any chance to save them all in the same pdf file?

Comment: @jo.H You'd need to look into `facet()` but you need a grouping variable in your data to do this. This is a good resource for `facet`s: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/ If you struggle I'd open a new question and post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)